# Get request for Google QR code API jQuery

Tags: jquery, get, google-visualization

I'm just getting into using Google APIs (exciting stuff).  I have an image tag on my page whose source attribute I want to get form the google charts API.  I haven't fiddled around with this stuff before so I've come up with:

```
  //root URL
    var qrURL = 'https://chart.googleapis.com/chart?'
    //text to make QR code
    var qrText = 'hello world';
    //parameters 
    var qrOptions = {
        cht: 'qr',
        chs: '300x300',
        ch1: qrText
    }
    $.get(qrURL + qrOptions, function () {

    });
    $('#img').attr('src', qrURL);
```

In the console this returns a bunch of wingding like characters which I assume is a text version of the QR code's picture.  What I would like to do, though, is actually dynamically get that image on my page.  What do I need to do to dynamically get the source attribute set like I want?

EDIT:
I added this: `$('#img').attr('src', qrURL + $.param(qrOptions));` but this gives me a QR code that when scanned contains no actual text (but it does let a QR code appear on the page).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your line, `$.get(qrURL + qrOptions, function...` is malformed: you cannot simply add an object to a string and expect a url-encoded string back. `qrURL + qrOptions` results in the string "https://chart.googleapis.com/chart?[object Object]" - not what you want. The proper parameters for `$.get` are [( url [, data ] [, success(data, textStatus, jqXHR) ] [, dataType ] )](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/)

The proper form for your get request is thus:

```
$.get(qrURL, qrOptions, function( reply ) { /* ... */ } );
```

You then proceed to use `reply` in your success function to handle Google's response.

Comment: Thanks for that info on the malformed string.  How I get the image out of the reply object? I tried setting the source attribute of the image tag, but to no avail.

Comment: Ha, totally missed it: your `qrOptions` uses `ch1` as the data parameter: it should be `chl` - so you've got a typo. Correct that and your `$('#img').attr('src', qrURL + $.param(qrOptions));` should work just fine

Comment: Sweet, so I wasn't too far off.  Good to know, thanks for the help.

Comment: Could you explain how you can do this with a GET request?

Comment: Unfortunately I don't think there's any way to do that - the `$.get` request returns the raw PNG data - so even tricks using `"<img src='data:image/png;base64," + btoa(reply) + "'/>"` wont work (as the reply contains characters outside the latin1 range and can't be converted to base64 - instead you'd have to find some PNG rendering method that could take the binary stream you get and display it. Your using jQuery to (re)assign the src of an img element is probably the only way you're going to get it in anything resembling brevity.